# Vertically align rows to 100% height

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am creating a news module for a website and i want to show the latest article with a big photo and 3 articles next to it. I am using Foundation 5.

You can see my current progress here :

[image]

```
<div class="large-5 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    <div class="smallnews">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-4 columns"><img src="i/andromeda-orbit.jpg" alt /></div>
            <div class="small-8 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-4 columns"><img src="i/andromeda-orbit.jpg" alt /></div>
            <div class="small-8 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-4 columns"><img src="i/andromeda-orbit.jpg" alt /></div>
            <div class="small-8 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My div is the exact same height as the bigger image. I am using Foundation's equalizer to do that. So basically I want a jQuery plugin or a css trick to make these 3 rows align to 100% of the parent height. I don't know how much text is there going to be in them.

Comment: the articles on the right always will be 3 or they may change?

Comment: @AhmedSalama always 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table` for the .smalnews and `display:table-row` width its rows like that :

```
.smallnews{
  display:table;
  height:100%;
}
.smallnews .row{
  display:table-row;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/drv7svym/

Comment: Great! I don't know where i messed up while trying it with table displays the first time but it worked now.

Answer (score 0):

Your three divs need to have `float:left;`, the `height` of `33.3%` and no margin.

Comment: That would work, but sometimes the text may be bigger than 33.3%